# Speed Up IMAP Process

Tags: node.js, email, imap

I have several thousands of IMAP accounts connected to my app. I need to check each of them on a regular basis (like every hour). It now takes way to long to run each updates and I was wondering how to drastically improve the speed of the queries.

If I add a ***after:xx/xx/xxxx*** would that increase each query vs checking for the last 2 years ?

Are there any other tips to achieve better performance ?

My server is running on Meteor Nodejs and I am mostly querying on Google and Outlook accounts.

Comment: Your question does not explain what you already tried to do in order to improve performance. Do you understand the nature of your queries? Where do they spend most of their time? What the result of a profiling is? Also, asking "would it help if I do X" is a bit rude given that you can very well do X yourself and see if it helps. Have you done that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try making IMAP requests non blocking to query multiple accounts at the same time.

Comment: I'm so sorry I am not sure I understood what you meant.

Comment: I just mean that you could use multiple threads to check multiple accounts in parallell, which could improve speed

Comment: Can you tell me if limiting the date range also reduces the response time  ?